# HostedService: The instance of entity type cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a web api with asp.net core 2.2 and ef core 2.2.1. The api, besides handling the restful requests made by an angular app, is in charge of processing some xml files that are used as an interface with other software. Files are local to the application server and detected through a `FileWatcher`.

I've noticed during my tests that when I reprocess multiple times an xml test file, starting from the second time the file is being reprocessed, I obtain the Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'QualityLot' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key
>   value '{QualityLotID: ...}' is already being tracked. When
>   attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with
>   a given key value is attached.

when I call the method `DbContext.QualityLot.Update(qualityLot);`

The "processing file" service and the service it's using are configured into the `Startup.cs` file as following:

```
services.AddHostedService<InterfaceDownloadService>();
services.AddTransient<IQLDwnldService, QLDwnldService>();
```

the db context is configued like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(cfg =>
{                
    cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("LIMSConnectionString"));
});
```

and the class looks like:

```
public class InterfaceDownloadService : BackgroundServiceBase
{
    [...]
    public InterfaceDownloadService(IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILogger<InterfaceDownloadService> logger, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    [...]
    private void processFiles()
    {
        [...]
        _ServiceProvider.GetService<IQLDwnldService>().QLDownloadAsync(ev);
    }
}

public abstract class BackgroundServiceBase : IHostedService, IDisposable
{

    private Task _executingTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts =
                                                   new CancellationTokenSource();

    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Store the task we're executing
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        // If the task is completed then return it,
        // this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        // Otherwise it's running
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Stop called without start
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Signal cancellation to the executing method
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite,
                                                          cancellationToken));
        }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _stoppingCts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Here the critical point, where I have the exception:

```
public async Task QLDownloadAsync(FileReceivedEvent fileReceivedEvent)
{
    Logger.LogInformation($"QLDwnld file {fileReceivedEvent.Event.FullPath} received for Processing");

    try
    {
        QualityLotDownload qualityRoutingDwnld = deserializeObject<QualityLotDownload>(fileReceivedEvent.XsltPath, fileReceivedEvent.Event.FullPath);
            Logger.LogDebug($"QLDwnld file {fileReceivedEvent.Event.FullPath} deserialized correctly. Need to determinate whether Insert or Update QualityLot {qualityRoutingDwnld.QualityLots.QualityLot.QualityLotID}");

        for (int remainingRetries = fileReceivedEvent.MaxRetries; remainingRetries > 0; remainingRetries--)
        {
            using (var transaction = await DbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    var qualityLotDeserialized = qualityRoutingDwnld.QualityLots.QualityLot;
                    // insert the object into the database
                    var qualityLot = await DbContext.QualityLot.Where(x => x.QualityLotID == qualityLotDeserialized.QualityLotID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                    if (qualityLot == null) // INSERT QL
                    {
                        await InsertQualityLot(qualityLotDeserialized);
                    }
                    else  // UPDATE QL
                    {
                        await UpdateQualityLot(qualityLot, qualityLotDeserialized);
                    }
                    [...]
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(ex, $"Retry {fileReceivedEvent.MaxRetries - remainingRetries +1}: Exception processing QLDwnld file {fileReceivedEvent.Event.FullPath}.");
                    transaction.Rollback();

                    if (remainingRetries == 1)
                    {

                        return;
                    }
                }
```

The method `UpdateQualityLot(qualityLot, qualityLotDeserialized);` is invoked because the entity already exists in the db

```
private async Task UpdateQualityLot(QualityLot qualityLot, QualityLotDownloadQualityLotsQualityLot qualityLotDeserialized)
{
    [fields update]
    DbContext.QualityLot.Update(qualityLot);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The call to `DbContext.QualityLot.Update(qualityLot);` fails.

From what I can see the instance of `QLDwnldService` is new for every file being processed, in other words the following method returns every time a new object (as configured into Startup.cs)

```
_ServiceProvider.GetService<IQLDwnldService>().QLDownloadAsync(ev);
```

, while the DbContext is reused and that's probably the reason why the entity results already tracked.

I also tride to setup the non-tracking option in the DbContext `OnConfiguring()`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder
        .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);  
}
```

So my question is. What's wrong here? Maybe an architecture problematic or maybe a misleading configuration of e core? Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I could not figure out where your DBContext is actually injected from your code.

But from the error message I'd say your context is reused in a place where it should not be. So it's injected once and then used over and over and over.

You have registered your service as "Scoped" (because that's the default).

You should register it as "Transient" to ensure you will get a new instance on every call to your service provider:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(cfg =>
{                
    cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("LIMSConnectionString"));
}, 
ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

---

Brad mentioned that this will have consequences for the rest of your application and he's right.

The better option might be to leave your `DbContext` scoped and inject the `IServiceScopeFactory` into your hosted service. Then create a new scope where you need it:

```
using(var scope = injectedServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>();

    // do your processing with context

} // this will end the scope, the scoped dbcontext will be disposed here
```

Please note that this still does not mean that you should access the DbContext in parallel. I don't know why your calls are all async. If you are actually doing parallel work, make sure you create one DbContext per thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. DBContext is actually injected through the constructor of QLDwnldService. I'll give a try to your suggestion  and let you know

Comment: Thank you man, indeed it worked. Do you think there could be any performance issue working this way?

Comment: This is not a good solution.  It may work but now all DbContext instances throughout the app are scoped Transient which may not be desired (Scoped is the default for a reason).  Alternatively, create a new `IServiceScope` in the `processFiles()` method using `_ServiceProvider.CreateScope()` and then resolve DbContext and all other services from this new service scope.

Comment: I think scoped DbContext confuses more. In addition to OP's problem, context cannot be used for simultaneous asynchronous queries.  Instead create a DbContextFactory class, inject it and every time you need context create new instance. DbContext is just a class, no extra connection will be opened ;).

Comment: @Brad You are right, I will add that later when I'm at a real keyboard :)